# Coloumbs law notation and math

Tags: electromagnetism, coulombs-law

I am currently taking Electricity and Magnetism I for Graduate school and we are of course using Jackson Classical Electrodynamics 3e. I am used to Griffiths from undergrad and intro physics in that they describe it:
[image]

But Jackson modifies the notation to include a cube of the magnitude in the denominator:

[image]

I have tried to wrap my head around it. My professor just said it makes it "less mathematically akward" which is fine. Can someone take me stepwise line by line why these two are the same? I would really appreciate it. I want to be sure that I am getting used to the notation early of Jackson as I hear that's the trickiest part. It's not "new" physics!

Comment: Have you tried to take the modulus and the direction of $\frac{\textbf{x}_1-\textbf{x}_2}{|\textbf{x}_1-\textbf{x}_2|^3}$, and compare to $\frac{1}{|\textbf{x}_1-\textbf{x}_2|^2}\hat{r}{}_{\textbf{x}_1-\textbf{x}_1}$?

Comment: $\vec v/|\vec v|^3=\hat v/|\vec v|^2$ because $\vec v=|\vec v|\hat v$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The notation $\hat r$ indicates a unit vector pointed in the same direction as $\vec r$, and $r=|\vec r|$ is the magnitude of $\vec r$.

So with that notation in place we have $$\vec r=r\ \hat r$$ or $$\hat r =\frac{\vec r}{r}$$

Then by substitution we get: $$\frac{1}{4\pi\epsilon_0} \frac{qQ}{r^2}\hat r = \frac{1}{4\pi\epsilon_0} \frac{qQ}{r^2}\frac{\vec r}{r} = \frac{1}{4\pi\epsilon_0} \frac{qQ}{r^3}\vec r$$

Comment: Thankyou so much, that clears it up for me and gets me on the right track as I continue my reading. I won't hesitate after I work a bit to come here again. Much gratitude!

Answer (score -2):

In the first equation Q is at r=0
so in the second just take x1 or x2=0 and you have the same.